# Android TextView.setText works after screen rotate

Tags: android, firebase-mlkit

Today I'm testing `google ml-kit` example.

I have rewritten `LivePreviewActivity` to show barcode value in `TextView`.
Barcode reading is good.
But `TextView` text changes only after rotating the screen or when we unlock the device.

Can you help me?

[Activity example](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1DLacliyKsrBHplCVMavb29oP29muNZMm/view?usp=drivesdk)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to everyone who puzzled over my question.
The reason for the inability to update the textview is a very hard request to get the barcode value.
Solution: it was necessary to wrap a heavy request in the Handler.